# Using Spock, how do you run a particular feature via the grails command line?

Tags: unit-testing, grails, groovy, spock, geb

I am running Spock tests for unit and functional tests. Awesome library.

I am wondering how to run a specific feature of a Spock Spec from the grails command line.

I know how to run all spock tests or run a specific spec but I don't know how to run a specific feature.

Thanks!

Comment: That is what I thought. Just confirming with the community. Thank you.

Comment: From what I've heard, Grails doesn't currently support this, except for JUnit. What you can always do is annotate a single method with @spock.lang.IgnoreRest and then run the class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Peter Niederwieser mentionned in his comment, this isn't possible with Spock. However, the annotation `@IgnoreRest` will serve the same purpose. Marking the question answered. Thank you